# How to get class properties or fields using reflection in Kotlin/Native?

Tags: kotlin, class, reflection, kotlin-native

I have a class like

```kotlin
class Foo {
  val bar = Bar()

  fun doSomething() {

  }
}
```

How do I get the fields or properties of the class Foo in doSomething?

Looking into `this::class` only has little available:
[image: autocomplete dropdown]

I added the reflect dependency but it does not appear to have done anything:

```
        val nativeMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("reflect"))
            }
        }
```

The class I'm writing is going to have a lot of properties which are all handled the same way so I'd like to iterate over them so that I don't have to manually write everything myself in a hard-coded fashion.

Comment: In this code want to get bar inside dosomething  function?

Comment: Yes, but using reflection, since there will be a lot more properties there.

Answer (score 1):

Reflection on Kotlin/Native is very limited. See the documentation pages for the [`kotlin.reflect`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/) package with the "Native" filter. The only useful things you can get out of a `KClass` are `simpleName`, `qualifiedName`, `isInstance`, `cast`, and `safeCast`.

While on the JVM you are forced to put lots of these reflection "metadata" into class files, having all that information emitted into a native binary would increase the size of the binary by a lot. From [here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/reflection/4054/12), this seems to go against the goals of Kotlin/Native (emphasis mine):

> The initial release of K/N will definitely not support Class.forName. The whole idea of K/N is to provide a “closed world” view of the code and **enable to build a highly-optimized and compact executable**. We believe that use-cases that require reflection in the way that you’ve described are perfectly covered by Kotlin/JVM already. We are not trying to build a better JVM.

As an idea, you can consider using some [annotation processing](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/ksp-quickstart.html) to generate a `List<KProperty>` for you to use. Something similar is also suggested in [this discussion](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-58974).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that it is very limited. Size is not an issue on my side, I just want it to work. How would I go about using annotations? As there is no reflection, I also don't know how to access those annotations.

Comment: @xdevs23 sorry, I was going to post a quick start link for KSP, the API to do annotation processing, but apparently I got distracted. I have edited it in now.

Comment: Thanks. The link you provided has a lot of jvm and jdk in the code snippets. Can you confirm that this works for Kotlin/Native? Also, all of this annotation processing really seems massively overkill just for getting a list of properties (not your fault, just stating my opinion).

Comment: @xdevs23 The compiler plugin would be written to target the JVM, since the Kotlin compiler is run on JVM. This is just a compiler plugin, unrelated to your actual production code. You can use the compiler plugin when compiling for any platform.

Comment: @xdevs23 And yes I agree this is overkill. Perhaps this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/), and there might be better solutions for your ultimate goal (which you haven't revealed).

Comment: Thanks for explaining. As to the possibility of this being an XY Problem, I agree that could be the case. The class I'm writing will (likely) have lots of properties at some point, all behaving the same, i. e. all of them have an `.init()` method that is invoked at a specific point and then a coroutine is launched for each of those properties which calls `.run()`. The reason for this is so that adding more of those objects would be a oneliner and I wouldn't forget to call .init() and .run() (or add it to the listOf()). But I still want to be able to access each of them directly.

Comment: As I'm used to writing Kotlin on the JVM, this would have been very easy to solve so I was trying to do it the same way here. Sadly the reliance on the JVM otherwise means that in the Native/MPP realm it's harder to do the same task.

Answer (score -1):

you can use this code instead of `this::class`.

In your example

```
bar::reference properties // here you will get
```

for more reference [Reflection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reflection.html#bound-constructor-references)

Comment: `::reference` does not exist for me and I want to get a *list* of properties not just a single property, because if it was just one, I could just use it directly and reflection would not be necessary.